# Kotlin Generic Function With Enum Constraint

Tags: kotlin, generics, enums, companion-object

I want to do something like the following:

```
inline fun<T: Enum<T>> myFunction(enumStr: String){
    T.valueOf(enumStr)
    //...
}
```

so that my generic parameter is constrained to be of enum class type so that I have access to the valueOf function. I am getting an error stating that:
`Type parameter 'T' cannot have or inherit a companion object, so it cannot be on the left hand side of dot`

which I understand to mean I can't use companion object functions on generics. Is there any way to achieve what I want - converting a string to a generic enum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you reify your type parameter, you can use the `enumValueOf` function ([doc here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/enum-value-of.html)).
Like this:

```
inline fun <reified T: Enum<T>> myFunction(enumStr: String) {
    val enumValue = enumValueOf<T>(enumStr)
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you *can't* make it `reified` as in @marstran's answer, you'll need to pass a `Class` and call [`Enum.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,java.lang.String)) (this solution is limited to JVM):

```
inline fun<T: Enum<T>> myFunction(enumClass: Class<T>, enumStr: String) {
    val value = Enum.valueOf(enumClass, enumStr) // T
    //...
}
```

Comment: how would I call this function? Meaning, given an EnumType, how can I pass it into the function?

Comment: `myFunction(EnumType::class.java, "foo")`